# How to set Google Drive ReadOnly files Permission for IOS app

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am integrating Google Drive SDK with the iOS app. I want to just read files from google drive. No upload or delete. How do I set ReadOnly files Permission during authorization. Here is my code.

```
-(void)setValuesForGoogleDriveAccess
{
    // Initialize the drive service & load existing credentials from the keychain if available
    self.driveService = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];

    self.driveService.authorizer = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                                         clientID:kClientID
                                                                                     clientSecret:nil];
    self.driveService.

    NSLog(@"authorizer : %@", self.driveService.authorizer);

    parentIdList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission can be set while creating GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch. Set it to kGTLAuthScopeDriveReadonly. That gives read only permission.

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;
    authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDriveReadonly
                                                                clientID:kClientID
                                                            clientSecret:nil
                                                        keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
```

There are other permissions you can see it in GTLDriveConstants.h file

```
// Authorization scope
// View and manage the files and documents in your Google Drive
GTL_EXTERN NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDrive;                 // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
// View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive
GTL_EXTERN NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDriveAppdata;          // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata"
// View your Google Drive apps
GTL_EXTERN NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDriveAppsReadonly;     // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly"
// View and manage Google Drive files that you have opened or created with this
// app
GTL_EXTERN NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile;             // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
// View metadata for files and documents in your Google Drive
GTL_EXTERN NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDriveMetadataReadonly;  // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"
// View the files and documents in your Google Drive
GTL_EXTERN NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDriveReadonly;         // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
// Modify your Google Apps Script scripts' behavior
GTL_EXTERN NSString * const kGTLAuthScopeDriveScripts;          // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts"
```